# How to get ids of checked checkboxes from a nested repeater c# when I click a button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am in trouble with nested repeaters. I used two repeaters. Rpt1 and rpt2. I used rpt1ID in rpt1_ItemDataBound to retrieve data from dbo.rpt_2 .I got that output.

```
<form method="post" action="Default2.aspx" id="form1">
<div class="aspNetHidden">
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="/wEPDwUKMTAwOTY3Njk1OQ9kFgICAw9kFgICAQ8WAh4LXyFJdGVtQ291bnQCAxYGZg9kFgRmDxUBBXdoaXRlZAIDDxYCHwACARYCZg9kFgJmDxUBCXdoaXRlIGNhcmQCAQ9kFgRmDxUBBWJsYWNrZAIDDxYCHwACARYCZg9kFgJmDxUBCWJsYWNrIGNhdGQCAg9kFgRmDxUBBnllbGxvd2QCAw8WAh8AAgEWAmYPZBYCZg8VAQ15ZWxsb3cgZmxvd2VyZBgBBR5fX0NvbnRyb2xzUmVxdWlyZVBvc3RCYWNrS2V5X18WAwUccnB0MSRjdGwwMCRycHQyJGN0bDAwJGNiVGVzdAUccnB0MSRjdGwwMSRycHQyJGN0bDAwJGNiVGVzdAUccnB0MSRjdGwwMiRycHQyJGN0bDAwJGNiVGVzdFtBgK000gWzwpdFcFINp56BH3iEbpu32p0ucdmVkKqQ">
</div>

<div class="aspNetHidden">

    <input type="hidden" name="__EVENTVALIDATION" id="__EVENTVALIDATION" value="/wEdAAtOAOd9ybgP4HtwI1kjAG/MIN3G+dZU3QaatNlxgtD/xtMq/m65MPpIiFULd6envm8Yw3LjELwW1svU+QRcZXObI4OhWhKb5ze/nlyzwgtKpgcaK/fYMlrAwV8ml1fRddm1Nj+RQVgfhH19Mqy7JakoOGJJxEuYbMh7gt3d2UEgxjVWyspxiwdSrYPfy2ovFed8sdKhZF2WzHs512/4sp8RUbCI4mLLhd/eyEmnxetg1jh3iXH1t2bNB/y0oxlp17XcDdrSIJMmEc3BKiLo+WAV">
</div>
    rpt1 white<br>
            <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl00$hfRpt1ID" id="rpt1_hfRpt1ID_0" value="1">

                ---rpt2 white car  <input id="rpt1_rpt2_0_cbTest_0" type="checkbox" name="rpt1$ctl00$rpt2$ctl00$cbTest" checked="checked"><br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl00$rpt2$ctl00$hfCheckedCheckBoxes" id="rpt1_rpt2_0_hfCheckedCheckBoxes_0" value="1">



        rpt1 black<br>
            <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl01$hfRpt1ID" id="rpt1_hfRpt1ID_1" value="2">

                ---rpt2 black cat  <input id="rpt1_rpt2_1_cbTest_0" type="checkbox" name="rpt1$ctl01$rpt2$ctl00$cbTest" checked="checked"><br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl01$rpt2$ctl00$hfCheckedCheckBoxes" id="rpt1_rpt2_1_hfCheckedCheckBoxes_0" value="2">



        rpt1 yellow<br>
            <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl02$hfRpt1ID" id="rpt1_hfRpt1ID_2" value="3">

                ---rpt2 yellow flower  <input id="rpt1_rpt2_2_cbTest_0" type="checkbox" name="rpt1$ctl02$rpt2$ctl00$cbTest" checked="checked"><br>

                    <input type="hidden" name="rpt1$ctl02$rpt2$ctl00$hfCheckedCheckBoxes" id="rpt1_rpt2_2_hfCheckedCheckBoxes_0" value="3">




        <input type="submit" name="btnFindCheckBoxes" value="Get Checked Textboxes" id="btnFindCheckBoxes">
    </form>
```

You cant see but there are checkboxes after each rpt2 line. My question is how can I get the ids of checked checkboxes when I click a button. I can get ids of checkboxes but I couldnt find a way how to get them when I clicked a button. my codes are below. I appreciate every answer. And please dont be angry if I did wrong something in this message. I am brand new here and it is my first message.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpt1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt1_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>rpt1 <%#Eval("rptName").ToString() %><br />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="hfRpt1ID" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("rpt1ID").ToString() %>' />
            <asp:Repeater ID="rpt2" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rpt2_ItemDataBound">

                <ItemTemplate> 
                ---rpt2 <%#Eval("rpt2Text").ToString() %>  <asp:CheckBox ID="cbTest" runat="server" Checked="true"/><br />

                    <asp:HiddenField ID="hfCheckedCheckBoxes" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("rpt1ID").ToString() %>' />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>


        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater> 
        <asp:Button ID="btnFindCheckBoxes" runat="server"  OnClick="btnFindCheckBoxes_Click" Text="Get Checked Textboxes"/>


protected void rpt1_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        boolArray();
        Repeater nestedRepeater = e.Item.FindControl("rpt2") as Repeater;
        d.Parameters.AddWithValue("rpt1Id", row["rpt1ID"]);
        nestedRepeater.DataSource = d.GetDataTable("Select * from rpt_2 where rpt1ID=@rpt1Id");
        nestedRepeater.DataBind();

    }


protected void rpt2_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem;
        int a = Convert.ToInt32(row["rpt2ID"]);
        CheckBox ch = e.Item.FindControl("cbTest") as CheckBox;
        if (ch.Checked)
        {
            findCheckboxes(a);
        }
    }

    private void findCheckboxes(int a)
    {
        xxxxx.Add(a);
        Response.Write(a + " cliecked-");
    }
```